# performance of insert with python and sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm doing big batch inserts into an SQLite3 database and I'm trying to get a sense for what sort of performance I should be expecting versus what I'm actually seeing.

My table looks like this:

```
cursor.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE tweets(
             tweet_hash TEXT PRIMARY KEY ON CONFLICT REPLACE,
             tweet_id INTEGER,
             tweet_text TEXT)"
        )
```

and my inserts look like this:

```
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO tweets VALUES (?, ?, ?)", to_write)
```

where `to_write` is a list of tuples.

Currently, with about 12 million rows in the database, inserting `50 000` rows is taking me around 16 minutes, running on a 2008 macbook.

Does this sound reasonable, or is there something gross happening?

Comment: Have you tried inserting multiple values in each query? Maybe not all of them at once, since you would have to create a very large string, but maybe 100 each? In my experience this improves insertion speed a lot.

Comment: @GustavLarsson: `executemany` is supposed to take advantage of preparing the query and streaming in the per-row columns *already*.

Comment: @GustavLarsson: How were you proposing creating multiple inserts? `execute()` and `executemany()` only allow for *one* statement.

Comment: i think something like `for i in range(0,len(my_list),100):execute_many(qry,my_list[i:i+100])` at a guess

Comment: Personally, I've never used `executemany`, so I don't know exactly how that works, or what optimization it gives you. What I was thinking of was doing something like `"INSERT INTO tweets VALUES (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)"` (in newer version of sqlite3, but there are work around in older), which I know is much faster than separate inserts. Maybe this method can be combined with `executemany` to make it buffered?

Comment: Does `executemany` use transactions? If not, sqlite will internally wrap each and every insert statement with an implicit transaction, which can cause a *huge* performance hit on bulk inserts. See these for a little more info: http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852068/sqlite-insert-very-slow

Comment: 16 minutes is a lot slower than I would expect. I think there is a good chance that @rutter comments are correct and each insert is being executed within an implicit transaction. I would store a large .sql file (or just a large string) with all of the inserts wrapped within a transaction(as discussed in the article above) and see how long this takes.

Comment: for some follow up I was never really able to satisfactorily resolve this problem. I did find better results with using smaller transaction sizes (around 1k entries) but still had performance problems, and ended up switching to gdbm, which is working better for this project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I understand the main reason of bad performance is time you waste to commit many SQLite transactions. What to do?

Drop the indexes, then

```
PRAGMA synchronous = OFF (or NORMAL)
```

Insert blocks of N rows (define N, try N=5000 to start).
Before inserting block do

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
```

after inserting do

```
COMMIT
```

See also http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19