# Python SQLite - How to manually BEGIN and END transactions?

Tags: python, sqlite, transactions

**Context**

So I am trying to figure out how to properly override the auto-transaction when using SQLite in Python. When I try and run

```
cursor.execute("BEGIN;")
.....an assortment of insert statements...
cursor.execute("END;")
```

I get the following error:

```
OperationalError: cannot commit - no transaction is active
```

Which I understand is because SQLite in Python automatically opens a transaction on each modifying statement, which in this case is an INSERT.

**Question:**

I am trying to speed my insertion by doing one transaction per several thousand records. 
**How can I overcome the automatic opening of transactions?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As @CL. said you have to set isolation level to `None`. Code example:

```
s = sqlite3.connect("./data.db")
s.isolation_level = None

try:
    c = s.cursor()
    c.execute("begin")
    ...
    c.execute("commit")
except:
    c.execute("rollback")
```

Comment: I've a question about this statement: "If you want autocommit mode, then set isolation_level to None.", does it mean, after we set the isolation_level as None, any kind of DML operation will be autocommit? So the performance couldn't be improved. Is my understanding is right? I jump here from this URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17867605/performance-of-insert-with-python-and-sqlite3

Comment: I have the same concern as @ClockZHONG. Based on some debugging I have done, I think that the documentation is misleading, and what it really should say is `If you want to manually handle transactions, then set isolation_level to None`.

Comment: I found [this on the official SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/get_autocommit.html) that clarifies what the python documentation was referring to by "autocommit". It seems that if no BEGIN statement is used, all statements execute in "autocommit" mode. So, as far as we enclose our statements with BEGIN/COMMIT, there is no such autocommit when isolation_level is set to None. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentaton](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#controlling-transactions) says:

> You can control which kind of `BEGIN` statements sqlite3 implicitly executes (or none at all) via the *isolation_level* parameter to the connect() call, or via the *isolation_level* property of connections.
>
> If you want autocommit mode, then set *isolation_level* to `None`.