# does sqlite ignore SQLITE_DEFAULT_SYNCHRONOUS define?

Tags: c, sqlite, sql-insert, transactional

I am using the amalgamation version 3.27.0 compiled with `SQLITE_DEFAULT_SYNCHRONOUS=0`, which ought to be the same as executing `PRAGMA synchronous=off` (but I am not executing this statement in my code, as I assumed the macro setting would be respected).

What happened was the infamous [`INSERT`](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19) delay after setting a number of rows. Wrapping in `BEGIN/COMMIT` solved the problem, as per the FAQ and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3852082/1095108), but I am left wondering. Is `SQLITE_DEFAULT_SYNCHRONOUS` ignored when compiling the amalgamation (i.e. I should not be noticing a delay with synchronous set to off)? . It does not seem that way when I look into the source code. In addition, I am enabling `WAL` on the database with `PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL`, which should be speeding up the inserts even more, but maybe doing so changes the `synchronous` pragma?

EDIT: If I execute `PRAGMA synchronous` in my program, sqlite returns `0`.

Comment: Perhaps related to ***Unfortunately, most consumer-grade mass storage devices lie about syncing.*** [https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html#_disk_drives_that_do_not_honor_sync_requests](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html)

Comment: I think, even if `PRAGMA synchronous` is 0, transactions bring some performance benefit. Now I added batching and it's even faster. Maybe I falsely thought that defining `SQLITE_DEFAULT_SYNCHRONOUS` as 0 would solve all problems.